# Issue Deploying Git Sync DAG to Airflow on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, rancher, git-sync

I have been trying to deploy the Git Sync DAG (v3.4.0) to my instance of Airflow (v2.4.1 with helm chart version 1.7.0) running on a kubernetes cluster (v1.23.7+rke2r2).

I followed the deployment instructions from the Airflow documentation which can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/manage-dags-files.html#mounting-dags-from-a-private-github-repo-using-git-sync-sidecar).

My `override_values.yaml` is the following.

```
dags:
  gitSync:
    enabled: true
    repo: git@github.com/MY_COMPANY_NAME/MY_COMPANY-dags.git
    branch: main
    subPath: ""
    sshKeySecret: airflow-ssh-secret
extraSecrets:
  airflow-ssh-secret:
    data: |
      gitSshKey: 'MY_PRIVATE_KEY_IN_B64'
```

Once airflow is stable, I use the following `helm` command to update my airflow deployment.

```
helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow --namespace airflow -f override-values.yaml
```

[image: Rancher Failures Screenshot]

This succeeds, but the deployment never achieves a new stable state with the `git-sync` containers.  The `git-sync-init` repeatedly fails to complete.  I have previously used this approach to deploy `git-sync` and it worked for months, however it stopped working suddenly.  When I attempt to check the logs for the `git-sync-init` container, they are empty and there doesn't seem to be a verbosity attribute I can enable.

After reading through github issues on the `git-sync` repo, I also attempted to prepend the `ssh://` scheme to the repo url, but that did not fix the issue.

Is there an alternative way for me deploy a `git-sync` sidecar container to my airflow deployment so that I can access code from private repos?

EDIT:

It appears like the issue was actually with the rancher GUI.  Whenever I would use the GUI, the container logs and shell would not load or show anything.  However, I was able to open up a `kubectl` shell, query for the airflow pods with `kubectl get pods -n airflow`, and query for the specific `init` container logs with `ubectl logs airflow-scheduler-65fcdbb58d-4pnzf git-sync -n airflow`.

This yielded the following error.

```
"msg"="unexpected error syncing repo, will retry" "error"="Run(git submodule update --init --recursive --depth 2): exit status 128: { stdout: "", stderr: "fatal: No url found for submodule path 'COMPANY_NAME/PACKAGE_PATH/PACKAGE' in .gitmodules\n" }"
```

This pointed to a misconfigured `.gitmodules` that was not updated when the structure of our `dag` repo was changed.